# PHP MAMP not showing all of HTML document

Tags: php, html, header, mamp

I am using MAMP. None of my code after the PHP tags displays in a browser.

I suspect it's something related to what content I can send to the browser after sending PHP? Or what content can be sent before the HTML doc?

Code:

```
<?php 
   /* Web Controller for searching music */
   session_start();     

   echo "I display fine!";
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Listen2me</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Listen2.me</h1>         
        <input type="text" name="songChoice" value="Search songs">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using WAMP I tested your code and the string was outputted correctly. It works fine for you inside the body tag?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save the file as .php? Can happen.

Comment: If I didn't save as .php the code inside the PHP tags wouldn't echo.

Comment: I bet it's a MAMP setting about sending whitespace or something..

Comment: ok, I misunderstood the question. The HTML code is the one not outputting? As far as I know there is no limitation and it should output both, as it did with me using WAMP.

Comment: do you have display_errors/error_reporting turned on? If not, then do so - there's a bug somewhere, and actively hiding the things that could tell you what the problem is just makes your job that much harder.

Comment: No issue with the code. As stated above, try to enable error reporting in your php.ini. Find "Error handling and logging" and replace the error_reporting line with the settings you want. All options are described in the file itself. Make sure you touch the right php.ini file in MAMP.

Comment: Works fine for me in MAMP 2.0.5

Comment: What browser are you using to test the page?
As many others it shows up in my browsers (Opera, Firefox, Safari and Chrome) using MAMP 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the missing doctype declaration could affect the display:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uploading the file to a different server to see if it's a problem with your localhost or a problem with your file?

When I run into issues where the code looks fine but it's not working fine, I always run it through BBEdit's "zap gremlins" feature. You might have an invisible bad character in there somewhere that's messing stuff up. If you don't have BBEdit, you can recreate the document from scratch. Don't copy-paste, because you'd just be copy-pasting any bad characters right back into the new document.